# Canonical path not working

Tags: java, path, relative-path

So I'm trying to use the canonical path to access a sound file, but it does not seem to work. Here is my code:

```
// load wave data from buffer
WaveData wavefile = WaveData.create("/Users/spex/NetBeansProjects/spaceinvaders/src/spaceinvaders/spaceinvaders/" + path);
```

It appears that it is trying to get the path from the location of the class path. Is there a way to let it know that I want to input the canonical path rather than a local one?

Comment: WaveData is not part of the JDK or JRE. You will have to find out how it interprets its parameters. We can't guess. This has nothing to do with 'canonical' pathnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a URL instead, as stated in the [javadocs](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/WaveData.html#create%28java.net.URL%29):

```
WaveData wavefile = WaveData.create(new URL("file:/Users/spex/NetBeansProjects/spaceinvaders/src/spaceinvaders/spaceinvaders/" + path));
```

Alternatively, create an input stream from your file, and the call [`WaveData.create(inputStream)`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/WaveData.html#create%28java.io.InputStream%29).